# How can I define a Regex to remove [xx]xxxxx[arch] xxx from a string?

Tags: regex

I have a complicated regex that I need to implement and would appreciate advice. Here I will give some examples as that might be the most easy way  to explain:

Before:

```
[10][pref]
  insufficient; incomplete; half-baked; half-hearted; perfunctory
[11][n][arch]
  cash
[12][n][abbr]
  tipsiness
```

After

```
[10][pref]
  insufficient; incomplete; half-baked; half-hearted; perfunctory
[12][n][abbr]
  tipsiness
```

Before

```
[1][pn][uk]
  this (indicating an item near the speaker, the action of the speaker, or the current topic)
[2][pn][hum]
  this person (usu. indicating someone in one&#39;s in-group)
[3][adv]
  now
[4][pn][arch]
  here
[5][pn][arch]
  I (me)
[6][adv][arch]
  certainly
```

After

```
[1][pn][uk]
  this (indicating an item near the speaker, the action of the speaker, or the current topic)
[2][pn][hum]
  this person (usu. indicating someone in one&#39;s in-group)
[3][adv]
  now
```

So what I would like to do is to remove all instances of:

> [xx]xxxxx[arch]   xxx

Where the start of the search string is a number in brackets, where there is an [arch] in the middle of the string and where the end of the search string is either a "[" for the next term or the end of the string.

What I am hoping to get is a Regex suggestion something like this:

```
regex = new Regex(@"(\n  )?\[arch]*\]");
```

That I could then use with:

```
regex.Replace(item.JmdictMeaning, "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?m)^\[\d+](?:\[[^][]*])*\[arch].*(?:\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t].*)*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%5C%5B%5Cd%2B%5D%28%3F%3A%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D%2A%5D%29%2A%5C%5Barch%5D.%2A%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D.%2A%29%2A&i=%5B10%5D%5Bpref%5D%0D%0A%20%20insufficient%3B%20incomplete%3B%20half-baked%3B%20half-hearted%3B%20perfunctory%0D%0A%5B11%5D%5Bn%5D%5Barch%5D%0D%0A%20%20cash%0D%0A%5B12%5D%5Bn%5D%5Babbr%5D%0D%0A%20%20tipsiness&r=)

- `(?m)` - a DOTALL modifier
- `^` - start of a line
- `\[\d+]` - a `[`, 1+ digits, `]`
- `(?:\[[^][]*])*` - zero or more sequences of `[`, 0 or more chars other than `[` and `]`, `]`
- `\[arch]` - an `[arch]` substring
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\r?\n[\p{Zs}\t].*)*` - 0 or more lines that start with a horizontal whitespace and then having any 0+ chars.

Unfortunately, .NET regex does not support the `\h` shorthand for horizontal whitespaces, so `[\p{Zs}\t]` is required (`\p{Zs}` does not match tabs by itself).

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out and let you know if it worked okay.